# API Twitter: I want to exclude an specific argument using api.search

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to get tweets that contains a specific subject. I want to see what customers are talking about the company 'this_company', but I don't want the tweets from 'this_company'. Therefore, I want to **exclude** screen_name = 'this_company'

I'm using:

```
posts = api.search(q = 'this_company', lan='en', tweet_mode = 'extended', since = '2020-07-10'
```

I tried to put screen_name != 'this_company', but it doesn't work (I don't think I can pass an argument with **!=**).

Does someone know how I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use operators directly in the query, as per the search API.  (Some examples [here](https://unionmetrics.com/resources/how-to-use-advanced-twitter-search-queries/).)

So you could search with `q = "this_company -from:this_company"`

(Untested code- some quoting might be necessary.)